# Template Gmock not recognized as correct argument type

Tags: c++, templates, googlemock

I wrote a small class to be used and a mock for it, and then I decided to change the class to be templated. However, after changing it to be templated, the mock is not longer accepted as an argument.

I templated my mock following this source: https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/cheat_sheet.md#mocking-a-class-template-mocktemplate
So it looks like this

```
template <class K, class V>
class MockClient : public Client<K, V> {
 public:
  explicit MockClient() : Client<K, V>() {}

  MOCK_METHOD1_T(..., void(const Config& config));
};
```

The mock is then passed in as an argument to create an object. I get an error like this about that:

```
candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'unique_ptr<MockClient<long, Metadata>, default_delete<MockClient<long, ModelMetadata>>>' to 'unique_ptr<Client<long, Metadata>, default_delete<Client<long,ModelMetadata>>>' for 1st argument
```

So it looks to me like it's not accepting the gmock as the same object like it was before and like it should?

I suspect that my mock constructor is missing something but I can't find a better source on templated mocks that includes how to do the constructor. Anyone know about this?

Comment: What is gmock? What is the macro MOCK_METHOD1_T ?

Comment: @JimmyNJ gmock is a Google mock framework. Used to create Mock objects for testing

Comment: According to this documentation (https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/cook_book.md) the `MOCK_METHOD_T` is an old MACRO. Can you try to use `MOCK_METHOD` instead? 
Please, provide the code where you are using this mock class.